# Each element of dual space is compactly supported

Tags: functional-analysis

My question is about a statement from “[Geometric Integration Theory](https://www.math.wustl.edu/%7Esk/books/root.pdf)” written by Steven G. Krantz and Harold R. Parks.

In chapter 7.1 on page 179 they state that

> each element of $\varepsilon’(U,V)$ is compactly supported
>
> [image]

Where they define:

> [image]

and

> We define $\varepsilon’(U,V)$ to be the set of all continuous, real-valued linear functionals on $\varepsilon(U,V)$.

---

**How do they know that the compact set $K$ from their explanation actually exists?**

Comment: You might want to include the definition of $\nu_K^i$ here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This follows from a standard criterion for continuity of linear maps on topological vector spaces whose topology arises from a family of seminorms. A slightly simplified version of this result is;

> **Lemma:** Let $X$ be a vector space whose topology is induced from a family of seminorms $\{\rho_i\}_{i \in I}$ and let $Y$ be a normed space. Then a linear map $L:X \to Y$ is continuous if and only if there is $i \in I$ and $C > 0$ such that $\|Lx \|_Y \leq C \rho_i (x)$ for all $x \in X$.

Since the topology of $\mathcal{E}(U,V)$ is induced by the family of seminorms $\{\nu_K^i: i \in \mathbb{N}, K \subseteq U \text{ compact}\}$, the existence of $K$ and $i$ follows immediately by applying the lemma with $X = \mathcal{E}(U,V)$ and $Y = \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is the reference that I needed. Am I right that in order to apply the Lemma I need to make the $I$ incorporate all the possible choices of compact $K$? It would result with an uncountable family of seminorms.

Comment: You need that index set to range over some family of seminorms which induce the topology of $\mathcal{E}(U,V)$. One way to do this is to make $I$ incorporate all $(i,K)$ with $i \in \mathbb{N}$ and $K \subseteq U$ compact. This gives an uncountable family. The usual way to get a countable family is to take a compact exhaustion $\{K_j\}_{j \geq 1}$ of $U$ and then the countable family of seminorms $\{\nu_{K_j}^i\}_{i,j \geq 1}$ will induce the same topology so you can work with those instead.